# node js code output on html web page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm fetching application details from the play store using the application package name.
The information that i want to print is not getting printed on the web page and html as well.

the node js code (server .js) is

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var formidable = require("formidable");

var util = require('util');

var googlePlaySearch = require('google-play-search');

var appName = " ";

var gameData = " ";

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    if (req.method.toLowerCase() == 'get') {

        displayForm(res);

    } else if (req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {

        processAllFieldsOfTheForm(req, res);

    }

});

function displayForm(res) {

    fs.readFile('form.html', function (err, data) {

        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html',
            'Content-Length': data.length

        });

        res.write(data);

        res.end();

    });
}



function processAllFieldsOfTheForm(req, res) {

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();


    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {

        //Store the data from the fields in your data store.

        //The data store could be a file or database or any other store based
        //on your application.
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'content-type': 'text/plain'


        });
        var url = fields;
        googlePlaySearch.fetch(url, function (err, gameData) {
            console.log(gameData);
            appName = gameData;
            res.write('received the data:\n\n');
            res.end(util.inspect({
                fields: appName,
            })); //for end

        }); //for parse
    });

}

server.listen(1185);

console.log("server listening on 1185");`enter code here`
```

and the html code is(form.html) :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="PACKAGE NAME" />
                <br />
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help me with the code.
Thank you.